# Google Cloud Functions: missing main.py

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When trying to deploy a Python project to Google Cloud functions using the command

`gcloud functions deploy my_function --entry-point reply --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated`

I get

> Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...⠛
> For Cloud Build Stackdriver Logs, visit:
> https://[...]
> Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build
> failed: missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified.
> Either create the function in main.py or specify
> GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE to point to the file that contains the
> function; Error ID: 5c04ec9c

But I do have a `main.py` file in the folder.

I checked the platform and the file `main.py` is not being uploaded, while the files inside folders are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to omit this line from `.gcloudignore`:

```
#!include:.gitignore
```

I don't really understand why.

My `.gitignore` is:

```
.*
*.json
```

Comment: To anyone else ending up here with the same Error: the offending line here seems to be `.*` in `.gcloudignore`. My intention was to ignore all dot-files, but in actuality it (also) ignores all files in the current directory. Therefore the `main.py` is ignored. The odd thing is that `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload` correctly reports `main.py` to be included in the upload, yet it is not shown in the cloud build logs, i.e. not part of the source archive uploaded to Google Cloud Build.

Comment: I ran into the same thing trying to exclude dot-files with `.*`.  The problem seems to be `gcloud functions deploy` internally prepends `./` to paths and then `.*` matches the leading `.` part (with verbosity set to debug it reported `Skipping file [./main.py]`).  My workaround was to use the pattern `.?*` instead.

Comment: Mine was main.py.py  I had to enable extensions in Windows to realize this

Answer (score 2):

I keep getting back to this topic as I wrongly zip my folder.  If you are using MacOS, ensure that you only include specific files inside the folder when zipping, as shown below:

```
zip myzipfile.zip constants.py main.py README.md requirements.txt
```

By doing this, any undesirable files like .DS_Store or .git will be excluded from the resulting compressed zip folder.

Answer (score 0):

The content of `.gcloudignore` which worked for me like a charm. I copied it from some other project which already had this autogenerated file.

FileName: `.gcloudignore`

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore
node_modules
```